# Why is the password stored in a raw format to the database in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I have this Serializer:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):

        name = validated_data['name'],
        id = validated_data['id'],
        user = Person.objects.create(name=name,
                                        password=validated_data['password'],
                                        id=id)

        return user
```

I thought that passwords are automatically saved as hashs in the database but with this serializer the password is saved in a raw format. How could I modify this to save the hash, not the raw version?

Edit. Here is my Person model and my UserManager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, name, password):

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user



class Person(AbstractBaseUser):

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, blank=False, max_length=100)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'name'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

As you can see, the name is here used as the username. Where do you define the password hashing, in serializer or in my `models.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the password like this.

```
user = Person(name=name, id=id)
user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
user.save()
```

`set_password` method takes care of hashing.